# jquery validation and ajax call firing at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

```
    $("#submit-button").click(function() {

        if($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" ) {
            $(".error-message-email").show();
        }
        if($.trim($("#password").val()) === ""){
            $(".error-message-password").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
    $("#submit-button").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:" " ,
    data:{"email": email, "password": password},
    success:function(data) {

        if(data["success"] === "True") {
                   // do something.
                 } else {

            if(data["message"] === "Email already exists.") {
                $(".error-message-email-exist").show();
            }       

                 }
    },
    dataType:"json"
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

I have problem. If error occured then how to stop ajax call to fire. Because here still my form failed to pass the validation, ajax call fired. I want to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't separate your click event.

```
$("#submit-button").click(function() {
    var error = false;
    if($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" ) {
        $(".error-message-email").show();
        error = true;
    }
    if($.trim($("#password").val()) === ""){
        $(".error-message-password").show();
        error = true;
    }

    if(!error) {

          $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url:" " ,
              data:{"email": email, "password": password},
              success:function(data) {

                  if(data["success"] === "True") {
                         // do something.
                  } else {

                  if(data["message"] === "Email already exists.") {
                      $(".error-message-email-exist").show();
                  }       

                  }
              },
              dataType:"json"
         });

    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 $("#submit-button").click(function() {
        var error = false;
        if($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" ) {
            $(".error-message-email").show();
            error = true;
        }
        if($.trim($("#password").val()) === ""){
            $(".error-message-password").show();
            error = true;
        }
        if (!error) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:" " ,
                data:{"email": email, "password": password},
                success:function(data) {

                    if(data["success"] === "True") {
                   // do something.
                    } else {

                    if(data["message"] === "Email already exists.") {
                        $(".error-message-email-exist").show();
                    }       

                 }
            },
            dataType:"json"
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have binded `click` twice and written the ajax call in the second one, it is firing regardless of the first one. It is totally independent.